# How to extract the text from the HTML using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have this HTML:

[image]

And **I want get this text** "*rataoriginal*". (This text changes, I need this part of the code as text)

I've tried

```
xpath = "//span[@class='_5h6Y_ _3Whw5 selectable-text invisible-space copyable-text']"
auxa = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).text
print(auxa)
```

But it prints the same as print("\n"). I don't want to use beaultifulsoup for a while.

This HTML is from 'https://web.whatsapp.com'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) is a dynamic element, so to print the values you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.selectable-text.invisible-space.copyable-text[dir='auto']"))).text)
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(@class, '') and contains(@class, 'invisible-space')][contains(@class, '') and @dir='auto']"))).text)
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a relevant discussion in:

- [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240245/how-to-retrieve-the-text-of-a-webelement-using-selenium-python/55241232#55241232)

Answer (score 0):

//*[contains(text(),"rataoriginal")] please use this xpath

Comment: Hello. I don't wanna to select this element, I need to get this text, it means that this text will change.

Comment: you can get that text by gettext(); in selenium